# Increment minutes in YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am not able to figure out where I am making a mistake. Is the below syntax of adding minutes to date in specified format correct

```
        startDate=2018-05-01
        sDate=$(date -d "$startDate" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ' )
        offset=5
        midDate=${sDate}
        echo 'mid Date before operation' ${midDate}
        midDate=$(date -d "${midDate:0:4}-${midDate:5:2}-${midDate:8:2}T${midDate:11:2}:${midDate:14:2}:${midDate:17:2}.${midDate:20:3}  +  ${offset} minutes "  '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ' )
        echo 'mid Date after operation' ${midDate}
```

**Output**

```
$bash -f main.sh
mid Date before operation 2018-05-01T00:00:00.000Z
mid Date after operation 2018-04-30T19:01:00.000Z
```

Comment: You can avoid substring operations altogether: `date -d "$startDate + 1 minutes" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ'`

Comment: Is `Z` supposed to be Greenwich Mean Time (in which time, you should use +0000) instead), or did you forget the `%` to have `%Z` expand to the local time zone?

Comment: As is, the `Z` makes `date` treat the timestamp as if it is in +0000, so it converts it to your local timezone first.

Answer (score 1):

try working with unix time e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
start_date=2018-05-01
offset_mins=5
start_unix=$(date -d "${start_date}" +%s)
end_unix=$((start_unix + 60*offset_mins))
end_date=$(date -d "@${end_unix}" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ')
printf "%s" ${end_date}
```